# Hover statement if width is > than

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-hover

I'm changing the background of a parent div when hovering over a child element. This should work only for screen sizes of 720px and greater, so I'm using this:

```
if ($(window).width() > 720) {
    $('div a').hover(
        function () {
            $('div').css("background-image", 'url(image-hover.png)');
        },
        function () {
            $('div').css("background-image", 'url(image.png)');
        });
    }
```

But the background still changes on smaller screens. What am I missing?

Comment: It is probably a better idea to use CSS media queries. The thing is that your script doesn't handle live viewport resizes, as it only checks the viewport width once on DOM ready. Otherwise, you'll have to call off the hover function, and rebind new ones (conditionally) for every viewport resize event, using `.off()`.

Comment: I would much prefer to use media queries, but since I need to change the parent element...

Comment: What you can do is to add/remove a class, and then use media queries to target that classs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest placing the width-check inside your event handlers rather than on the outside. This way you will be testing the current viewport, not the viewport when the page loads.

Pseudo-example:

```
$([selector]).on('mouseleave', function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 720) {
        ...
    }
}).on('mouseenter', function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 720) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: The only issue is that in the event of the viewport size changing during the hover event... you'll risk the element being stuck in a certain state.

Comment: @Terry The window changes when the hover occurs? This seems very improbably as a hover event is fired by the mouse being over an element in your DOM and you are probably needing to un-hover that DOM element to change the size of the browser window. An alternative would be to save the width of the viewport in a variable, check that variable in your event handler(s), and update the variable in a `window.resize` event handler.

Comment: Of course, highly improbable but sometimes you have to expect the least expected ;) like firing a DOM inspector upon hover by a keyboard shortcut, perhaps?

Comment: @Terry I wouldn't suggest anything more before knowing more about the OP's setup.

Comment: Just pointing out that your answer is very legit and correct, but not entirely foolproof ;)

Comment: @Terry Responsive design opens up all kinds of fun intricacies.

Answer (score 0):

I should take a look at your full code to know why your code is not working.

But I don't understand why you're not using a regular css hover function.

Why not add

```
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  .div a {
    background: url(image.png);
  }

  .div a:hover {
    background: url(image-hover.png);
  }
}
```

to your css file?

Comment: I need to change the parent background when hovering over the child, I can't do that with CSS :(

Answer (score -1):

try this "screen.width"

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
"Screen width is " + screen.width;
</script>

if (screen.width > 720) {
    $('div a').hover(
        function () {
            $('div').css("background-image", 'url(image-hover.png)');
        },
        function () {
            $('div').css("background-image", 'url(image.png)');
        });
    }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp